# Allow apostrophe when using ctype_alpha?

Tags: php, validation

I know there's are other ways to do it, but I'm playing with validating a name field using ctype_alpha but allowing spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes.

Per another post on Stack, I was able to add the spaces no problem, but I'm thinking I have the syntax wrong for replacing multiple characters.

**What I've used so far that works for validating that only letters and spaces are allowed:**

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $name)) === false) {
    echo'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
    exit;
}
```

This removes any spaces before checking that the string is letters only.  I was looking to simply add to this to also allow hyphens and apostrophes.

**What I've tried for adding hyphens and/or apostrophes (doesn't work):**

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', '-', '', $name)) === false) {
    echo'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
    exit;
}
```

My guess is that adding a second string in the str_replace function is not proper syntax, but being a PHP newb, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to phrase my searches to find the correct syntax.

Also, am I correct in saying that '\w' will cover my apostrophes once I figure out the correct syntax for the str_replace function?

Genuinely appreciate the help guys.  You're all invaluable and I try hard not to abuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the proper syntax, as stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is:

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' ', '', '-'), '', $name)) === false) {
    echo'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
    exit;
}
```

With  apostrophe

```
if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' ', '', '-',"'"), '', $name)) === false) {
    echo'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This absolutely works for adding the hyphen but I'm assuming I can't just add an apostrophe in there.  I tried '\w' and '\w+' per another post, but neither seem to be working correctly.

In other words, I tried:

        if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' ', '\w+', '-'), '', $name)) === false) {
            echo'Name must contain letters and spaces only';
            exit;
        }

... with a couple other variations of '\w+'.

Comment: @sforcash  apostrophe added

Answer (score 3):

Using '\w' is unfeasible with respect to the apostrophe, i.e. a single quote character.  Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> \w     Any word character (letter, number, underscore)

As for the syntax in the OP's code, the primary issue is needing to have an array of characters for the first parameter of str_replace() in order to replace multiple characters.

In addition to enclosing a single quote in double quotes (`"'"`), PHP permits escaping the single quote character with a backslash and then enclosing it in single quotes, as the following snippet indicates:

```
<?php

$name = "Kate O'Henry-Smith";
$arrDelChars = [' ','\'','-'];

if ( ctype_alpha( str_replace( $arrDelChars, '', $name ) ) === false ) {
    exit( "Name must contain letters and spaces only\n" );
}

print_r($name);
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/WBUuh)

str_replace() replaces each character in $name with an empty string based on  an array of values to exclude.  Note, specifying the empty string in the array is needless since the replacement value is the empty string.  The new string which emerges becomes the actual parameter for ctype_alpha() instead of $name.  Accordingly the function returns true.  Consequently, the if-conditional evaluates as false, thereby preventing an error message from displaying.  Cute trick for allowing ctype_alpha() to validate $name so-to-speak.